# ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined when trying to test AsyncStorage

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my React Native app. I'm trying to mock a call to AsyncStorage and I'm using the `mock-async-storage` package. Following their instructions, I've set up their simple my test file looks like this:

```js
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "react-native";
import MockAsyncStorage from "mock-async-storage";
import { AsyncStorage as storage } from "react-native";

import Station from "../src/models/Station";
import * as actions from "../src/redux/actions/stationActions";

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

/* ...other tests  */

describe("async fetching actions", () => {
  describe("using MockAsyncStorage", () => {
    const mock = () => {
      const mockImpl = new MockAsyncStorage();
      jest.mock("AsyncStorage", () => mockImpl);
    };

    mock();

    it("Mock Async Storage working", async () => {
      await storage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");
      const value = await storage.getItem("myKey");
      expect(value).toBe("myValue");
    });
  });
});
```

Following the example on the package's repo, my tests folder has a `__mocks__` folder with this `AsyncStorage.js` file:

```js
import MockAsyncStorage from '../../../lib/mockAsyncStorage';

export default new MockAsyncStorage();
```

and these files in the tests folder:

```js
// AsyncStorage.js
export default {}

// UseStorage.js
import AsyncStorage from './AsyncStorage';

export const save = (k, v) => AsyncStorage.setItem(k,v);

export const get = k => AsyncStorage.getItem(k);
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
    ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined

      63 | 
      64 |     it("Mock Async Storage working", async () => {
    > 65 |       await storage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");
         |             ^
      66 |       const value = await storage.getItem("myKey");
      67 |       expect(value).toBe("myValue");
      68 |     });

      at Object.__DEV__ (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Performance/Systrace.js:27:28)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:14:18)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/BatchedBridge.js:13:22)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:13:23)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Storage/AsyncStorage.js:15:23)
      at Object.require [as AsyncStorage] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:180:12)
      at storage (tests/fetchStations.test.js:65:13)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee (tests/fetchStations.test.js:64:38)
```

I've tried many things suggested in other answers and nothing has helped:

- Adding `babel-preset-react-native` to my dev dependencies
- Adding `"globals": { "__DEV__": true }` to my `package.json` under `"jest"
- Switching my `jest preset` from `jest-expo` to `react-native`
- Adding `/* global __DEV__ */` at the top of my test file

How do I make this work??

Small update: This may actually not have anything to do with mocks. I've removed all attempts to mock AsyncStorage, and tried just testing my method that uses AsyncStorage. All I've done is:

```js
describe("fetchStations(useCache)", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await store.dispatch(actions.fetchStations({ useCache: true }));
    });

    xit("should return an object with the stations in a 'stations' key", () => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(
        expect.arrayContaining(expectedGetActions)
      );
    });
  });
```

Where `actions.fetchStations` includes a call to `AsyncStorage.getItem`. And I get the same `__DEV__ is not defined` error.

Answer (score 1):

If you [configure `jest` to use the `react-native` preset](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#setup), it will set up the [react native javascript environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment) for you including the global `__DEV__` variable.